# Content-Length Incorrect When Trying to POST FormData

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch-api, multipartform-data

I'm trying to POST a FormData object containing either `readFileSync` or `createReadStream`. The `getLengthSync` function from form-data isn't working in this instance. Is there an alternative way to calculate the Content-Length for a Form with multiple fields (& boundary separators)?

```
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';
import FormData from 'form-data';

const requestData = new FormData();
requestData.append('csv', readFileSync(fileNameWithPath));
requestData.append('text', value);

const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authToken,
        'Content-Length': requestData.getLengthSync(),
        ...requestData.getHeaders()
    },
    body: requestData
});
```

Unfortunately, fetch will not auto generate any of my headers outside of a browser, otherwise I would just utilize the FormData object included in the latest versions of Node. The `requestData.getHeaders()` function successfully adds the Content-Type header with boundary, but not a Content-Length header.